# install CakePHP on Mac osx: apache problems

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, apache2, installation

First time cake user and I'm having real apache problems. For some reason the .htaccess is trying to find

```
File does not exist: /Library/WebServer/Documents/Users
```

but there is no such directory as Users. I have tried setting up the following also:

**/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80 >
DocumentRoot "/Users/username/Sites/mysite/app/webroot"
ServerName mysite.dev
ServerAlias www.mysite.dev mysite.dev *.mysite.dev
<Directory "/Users/username/Sites/mysite/app/webroot">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   mysite.dev
```

**/etc/apache2/users/username.conf**

```
<Directory "/Users/username/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

That also hasn't worked, but with a different error Failed opening required 'cake/libs/cache/file.php'

Although I'd rather not use virtual hosts, and just run it off localhost

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems like the solution that worked for me was to edit /etc/apache2/users/username.conf and add this at the top:

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/username/Sites"
```

And the default cakePHP download now runs ok.

Comment: This worked for me too. But I'd like to understand: why is this line needed? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like Apache is trying to find your webroot in a different location--the default location, if memory serves. If you want to use virtual hosts (which would be my recommendation, for whatever it's worth), ensure that the `NameVirtualHost` directive is uncommented. By default, it's commented out:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

If you'd prefer *not* to use virtual hosts for whatever reason, ensure that the `NameVirtualHost` *is* commented out (your `<VirtualHost>` blocks will be ignored) and change the `DocumentRoot` value to the proper directory:

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/username/Sites/mysite/app/webroot"
```

That should tell Apache to look in the right place.