# UPDATE CakePHP - The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, http-status-code-404

INSTALLING CAKEPHP FOR DUMMIES

If you are like me, you are frustrated with these frameworks like Ruby on Rails and CakePHP, which promise rapid development, despite sluggish start - simply spending hours on install.

To get CakePHP running, throw out the tutorials and don't even bother buying the books or reading the documentation. None of them mention to do exactly this but this is what needs to be done on Mac 10.6.2:

```
1) Install CakePHP to Sites and unzip it. Rename it to your application name.
2) Now your httpd.conf file can be located anywhere on your mac. Each tutorial assumes it's located at some place in the depths of virtual reality. But in reality all you need to do is use the handy unix command locate from the terminal: locate httpd.conf
4) Then whip out your editor: mate httpd.conf
5) make sure your DocumentRoot says this: DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
6) make sure under Directory it says AllowOveride All and Allow from all. It should have this by default but you never know when your sister randomly screws with your computer. Just be glad you have a mac and don't have to deal with her infesting your computer with viruses. 
7) Obviously you want the php module uncommented: LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
8) Now if you're like me, you dont want to type http://localhost/~jmerlino/mysite. You want to type http://localhost/mysite. So launch the hosts file. Again all you have to do is locate /etc/hosts and then mate /etc/hosts, assuming you're using TextMate. If you're using BBEdit, then obviously you won't be using the mate command.
9) Add this line: 127.0.0.1 localhost/mysite. This allows you to now use http://localhost/mysite.
10) Now the crazy part. find yur username.conf. For me, it's /etc/apache2/users/username.conf. For you, you do locate and make sure it's same spot. 
11) Add the following:
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost/sitename
DocumentRoot "/Users/username/Sites/"
</VirtualHost>
12) Don't put username. Put whatever your user name is. 
13) Then run your app off http://localhost/mysite.
14) Don't forget to sudo apachectl restart when you're finished.
```

If you have anymore issues, it doesn't mean you should give up programming and become a pipe cleaner. Just keep trying. Just remember you won't find the solution in one online tutorial.

Comment: try removing `app/webroot` from your `DocumentRoot` setting? or do those folders actually exist?

Comment: I did try to remove it from DocumentRoot setting. And strangely enough that error remained. And yes those files do exist. I tried it on another browser because I thought maybe cookies were issue. I also restarted apache. But still same error remaned despite removing app/webroot from documentroot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advice you to follow the installation instructions from the [bakery](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/momendo/2006/10/04/installing-cakephp-on-macos-x) and setup from [this](http://blog.creativeideal.net/cakephp/setting-up-cakephp-on-mac-os-x-with-mamp-pro) blog. Also take a look at this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486625/install-cakephp-on-mac-osx-apache-problems).

Comment: Your instructions say depress in /Library/WebServer/Documents
So I do
It says 
In /Library/WebServer/Documents type:
ln -s /Users/username/Sites/cake cake
So I do
Then edit your httpd.conf file. That's located here. /etc/httpd/httpd.conf
Unfortunately, there is no such file located there. The file is located in 
/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
So I go there and make following change:
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/cake/app/webroot" 
AllowOverride All  was already set to All
sudo  apachectl restart
Now I get Unable to Connect page

Comment: I changed DocumentRoot back to /Users/jmerlino/Sites and now it seems to be working. None of the tutorials I have read and none of the turorials you provided above mention to do this. However, it was that stackoverflow link you sent with the third question down that ultimately reminded me to check to see /Users/jmerlino/Sites.

Comment: I give you accepted answer. But the bakery link and blog you posted are outdated. It's the stackoverflow link you provided that offered the solution. And it was really the comment at the very bottom which had the solution, not even the one who was given the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Change document_root in your web server configuration. eg: `document_root /var/www`

Change this to `document_root /var/www/cake`. The `document_root` should point to your project.

Answer (score 0):

edit the core.php file in app/config/core.php

find this line in the code
    define('ABSOLUTE_URL',FULL_BASE_URL."");
and change this to `define('ABSOLUTE_URL',FULL_BASE_URL."subdirectory_name");`
eg: `define('ABSOLUTE_URL',FULL_BASE_URL."/cake");`